# Is there a way to make string a reference type in a collection?

Tags: c#

I want to modify some strings that are contained in an object like say an array, or maybe the nodes in an XDocument (XText)XNode.Value.

I want to gather a subset of strings from these objects and modify them, but I don't know at runtime from what object type they come from.

Put another way, let's say I have objects like this:

```
List<string> fruits = new List<string>() {"apple", "banana", "cantelope"};

XDocument _xmlObject;
```

I want to be able to add a subset of values from the original collections to new lists like this:

```
List<ref string> myStrings1 = new List<ref string>();
myStrings1.Add(ref fruits[1]);
myStrings1.Add(ref fruits[2]);

List<ref string> myStrings2 = new List<ref string>();
IEnumerable<XNode> xTextNodes = getTargetTextNodes(targetPath); //some function returns a series of XNodes in the XDocument
foreach (XNode node in xTextNodes)
{ 
    myStrings2.Add(((XText)node).Value);
}
```

Then change the values using a general purpose method like this:

```
public void Modify(List<ref string> mystrings){
    foreach (ref string item in mystrings)
    {
       item = "new string";
    }
}
```

Such that I can pass that method any string collection, and modify the strings in the original object without having to deal with the original object itself.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Modify(myStrings1);
    Modify(myStrings2);
}
```

The important part here is the `mystrings` collection. That can be special. But I need to be able to use a variety of different kinds of strings and string collections as the originals source data to go in that collection.

Of course, the above code doesn't work, and neither does any variation I've tried. Is this even possible in c#?

Comment: Strings are already reference types... they just have some extra support in the framework to give them value semantics in certain situations. Just being a reference type isn't good enough for this.

Comment: Hope the edit captures what you want for your question.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Close but I made some modifications to your change to better describe the situation.

Comment: Based on your change:  just use the IList interface. I'm editing my answer to explain.

Comment: Also, `XNodes` are **not** strings. You can't modify them like this in the first place, so what you're asking now makes no sense.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn sorry forgot the .Value

Comment: It still makes no sense. Even needing to access `.Value` property means your original collection is **not** a string collection.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm staring to get what you're after here. You're trying to transform an XDocument in a batch... you need to make the same change to a lot of nodes, and you want to preserve the original XDocument object, so that you can write it back to disc as some point. That just won't work the way you want. You'll find that you really need to populate a new XDocument for this.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, true, the original object may not always be a string collection in the form of an array type of collection.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yes, but not only do I have XDocuments, I have custom document type objects that are defined in terms of some other collection. For example Comma Seperated Value record with columns represented by maybe a string[] or List<string>

Answer (score 1):

What you want is possible with C#... **but only if you can [*fix*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28VS.80%29.aspx) every possible source for your strings.** That would allow you to use pointers to the original strings... at a terrible cost, however, in terms of memory management and [unsafe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx) code throughout your application.

I encourage you to pursue a different direction for this.

---

Based on your edits, it looks like you're always working with an entire collection, and always modifying the entire collection at once. Also, this might not even be a string collection at the outset. I don't think you'll be able to get the exact result you want, because of the base XDocument type you're working with. But one possible direction to explore might look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Modify(IEnumerable<string> items)
{
    foreach(string item in items)
    {
       yield return "blah";
    }
}
```

You can use a [*projection*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546168.aspx) to get strings from any collection type, and get your modified text back:

```
fruits = Modify(fruits).ToList();
var nodes = Modify( xTextNodes.Select(n => (XText)n.Value));
```

And once you understand how to make a projection, you may find that the existing `.Select()` method already does everything you need.

---

What I *really* suggest, though, is that rather than working with an entire collection, think about working in terms of one record at a time. Create a common object type that all of your data sources understand. Create a projection from each data source into the common object type. Loop through each of the objects in your projection and make your adjustment. Then have another projection back to the original record type. *This will not be the original collection*. It will be a **new** collection. Write your new collection back to disk.

Used appropriately, this also has the potential for *much greater performance* than your original approach. This is because working with one record at a time, using these linq projections, opens the door to streaming the data, such that only one the one current record is ever held in memory at a time. You can open a stream from the original and a stream for the output, and write to the output just as fast as you can read from the original.

Comment: Like perhaps choosing a different language? :)

Comment: @erotavlas, by changing your architecture. When something's particularly difficult to do, it's often a sign of a design problem. Perhaps instead of retrieving a set of strings from your object(s), you could instead pass a transforming function, (e.g. a `Func<string, string>`) to your object processor. This function would contain the code currently in your `Modify` method...

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie I agree I have design issues.  I'm trying to rethink the order in which I perform the operations.  I will try to do the 'inverse' of my current approach like you suggest.

Comment: The only thing not clear, and what prompted me to ask the original question, is when I modify the string I was trying to avoid finding where to replace it in the original object.  If a projection results in a subset of strings (say text nodes in an XDocument)  and I modify those, how do I get the modified strings back in their correct position on a copy of the original object  - how do I know where to put the modification back? They just can't go anywhere - imagine a modification to reverse the ordering of characters in each string.

Comment: You project the whole object to a known interface that accounts for all of the properties of the original, modify just the property that you need, and then project back to the original type to write back to disk.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The 'project back' part of your suggestion is what I'm not clear on, say I'm dealing with the XDocument and select a set of text nodes by element name using Descendants(). This gathers all the elements no matter where they are in the document. They become indistinguishable from each other.  What information could I store as a property that would enable me to get them back to their original locations after modifying them?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is by doing the looping outside of the method. This allows you to pass the strings by reference which will replace the existing reference with the new one (don't forget that strings are immutable).

And example of this:

```
void Main()
{
    string[] arr = new[] {"lala", "lolo"};
    arr.Dump();
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        ModifyStrings(ref arr[i]);
    }
    arr.Dump();
}

public void ModifyStrings(ref string item)
{
   item = "blah";  
}
```

Comment: For me the string[] arr is being filled with strings that are coming from other objects. I have two levels - an initial object (like XDocument or a string[] representing a Comma Separated Values record) and from that I create a subset of strings (like a result form a search) from that object.